# Passing Laravel route to vue component's Href or router-link

Tags: laravel, vue.js, vue-component, vue-router, laravel-blade

I'm creating a dropdown component with Vue 3 and importing it inside my Laravel 8 project. The dropdown works perfectly and looping over the categories in database as expected.

The issue is that i want when i click on a category it routes me to '/categories/$category->slug' which is defined in Laravel routes already and works if i enter it manually. But i can't find a way to say $category->slug in vue component.

Here is the component: [image: Dropdown Component]

I tried anchor tags and inside the href '/categories/{{category.slug}}' but it doesn't work. All i need is to have an anchor tag or router-link that directs me to '/categories/$category->slug'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay i solved it and it was pretty simple!

I simply added to data() the below code

```
categoryRoute: "/categories/",
```

Then adjusted the href like so

```
:href="this.categoryRoute + category.slug"
```